# Django ApiTestCase Leak

Tags: django, rest, testing

I am testing API Endpoints in Django (4.2.1) with `djangorestframework` version 3.14.0.
We have this code:

```
from django.core.management import call_command
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.authtoken.models import Token
from rest_framework.test import APITestCase
from account.models import Member, Organization, PhoneNumber
from authorization.models import AuthSMSCode


class SetUp(APITestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        # super().setUpClass()
        cls.username = 'sudo'
        cls.member = Member.objects.create_user(first_name='DefaultUser', email='default@gmail.com')
        cls.organization = Organization.objects.create(name="Google", legal_address='1040 Brussels')
        cls.member.organizations.add(cls.organization)
        cls.member.save()
        cls.organization.save()
        cls.phone_number = PhoneNumber.objects.create(number='9999999999', member=cls.member)
        code = 12345
        cls.smscode = AuthSMSCode.objects.create(value=code, phone_number=cls.phone_number)
        Token.objects.create(user=cls.member)
        call_command('create_default_roles')


class ApiTestCaseGroups(SetUp, APITestCase):

    def test_authorized(self):
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + self.member.auth_token.key)
        url = ...
        response = self.client.get(url, format='json', REMOTE_USER=self.username)
        expected_output = ...
        response_result = response.json()
        self.maxDiff = None
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(response_result, expected_output)


class ApiTestCaseMembers(SetUp, APITestCase):

    def test_authorized(self):
        self.client.credentials(HTTP_AUTHORIZATION='Token ' + self.member.auth_token.key)
        url = .....

        response = self.client.get(url, format='json', REMOTE_USER=self.username)
        expected_output = ...
        response_result = response.json()
        self.maxDiff = None
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, status.HTTP_200_OK)
        self.assertEqual(response_result, expected_output)
```

If we run `ApiTestCaseGroups` and `ApitTestCaseMembers` separately as classes, they work fine.
But when we run the whole file as a test `manage.py test` it fails on test №2 `ApiTestCaseMembers` because the object is empty (it returns code 200, so we authenticate, but there is no object inside `response_result`).

I saw some similar questions around, but those solutions did not work here.
In what direction should we go to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with primary key.Django creates and deletes databases all the time during tests, but new objects are created by next primary key (or id). So instead of using hardcoded ids like 1,2 , i firstly parsed them from setup and then put inside test itself.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).